# Matching the left and rights side side of a string using a regex

Tags: regex, splunk

In any regex language (PCRE preferred though) is there a way to negate matching a portion of a string in the middle? I've looked at both negative/positive lookahead/behind and those seem to be able to match either the left or right sides but not both at the same time (likely I'm misunderstanding something).

Some example inputs:

```
a "b" c
d "e" f
```

Expected matches:

```
a  c
d  f
```

The strings either the left or right can be any character/symbol, I essentially want to discard anything inside the `""`, including the quotes itself.

---

To make this more concrete, I'm trying to parse some error logs we have in Splunk where the names of Kubernetes pods are contains within the `""`. Removing the unique pod names would allow me to make a distinct list of error messages affecting the system I'm trying to triage.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can do it with `sed`.

```
...
| rex mode=sed "s/([^\\\"]+) \\\"[^\\\"]+\\\" (.*)/\1 \2/"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Splunk you can make use of groups like this:

````
...
| rex "(?<left>.*?)\"[^\"]*\"(?<right>.*)" ```captures only the left and right parts```
| eval pod=left+right                      ```concatenates left and right which essentially deletes the quoted part```
| table pod                                ```a table of results, just for illustration```
````